# Fire at enemy script doesnt work

Tags: unity, c#

I need my enemies to fire at me. I have a script and I think all is correct. I couldnt figure out why it doesnt work?

```
public class AntagonisticElCreator : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject boom;
public float enemySpeed;

public bool move=false;
public bool shoot=false;
public Transform character;
Vector3 pos;
int boomnumber;

 public float bulletSpeed;
public float bulletDestroyTime;

public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public Transform bulletSpawn;



void Start () {
   bulletSpeed = 15f;
bulletDestroyTime = 8f;
    NumbarofBullet = 105;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {


    pos = new Vector3(character.position.x, transform.position.y, character.position.z);
    distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, character.position);
    if (distance < 20){
        move = true;
        shoot = false;
        transform.LookAt(pos);

    }
    if (distance < 10)
    {
        move = false;
        shoot = true;


    }

    if (move)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, character.position, enemySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.LookAt(pos);
    }
    if (shoot)
    {
        shootAt();
    }

        void shootAt(){

        Instantiate(explsn, bulletSpawn.transform.position, 
        bulletSpawn.transform.rotation);
      var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, 
      bulletSpawn.rotation);       
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 
        bulletSpeed;



}


}
```

* */

Comment: Do you get any errors? Use Debug.Log for the distance transform, to se if it is firing: Debug.Log(distance). Also, where did you declared distance? Because in the script youve posted, there isnt a variable called distance.

Comment: distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, character.position); here i declared. i get no erors

Comment: That's an assignment, not a declaration. A declaration in C# would look like `float distance` or `var diatance`. How does the current behaviour of your script differ from what you want?

Comment: Hey! Yes, i saw that line of code, which is why the question came up where you call distance from. Did you Debug,Log it?

Comment: gives an eror saying that keyword void cannot be used in this context

Comment: This seems to be a simple C# syntax error not related to game development. Such general programming questions should usually be posted on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: it sasy variable character hasnt been assigned

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way which invalidates the answers you received. If the answers solved your problem but you have a new one, then you should accept the most helpful answers (by clicking on the checkmark-icon next to it) and post a new question about your new problem.

Comment: no, i edited because it didnt solve my problem

Comment: maybe you can look at this script and give your solution

Comment: your method "void ShootAt()" you have accidentally wrote it inside your void Update() method. Move it out of there and into other part of the code below it (the empty space - methods can't go inside other methods, and the void keyword indicates that you are making a method (one which returns nothing, ie. void)

Comment: NOTE: it will be helpful to add more information such as the error log in the debugger. Next time try to include as much information like that as possible at the time of posting, So that the experts here can just glimpse at it and quickly see what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to define a new method within the code of another method. C# does not allow you to do that until version 7.0 (which the current Unity version 2018.2 doesn't support yet).

Move the definition of the `void ShootAt` method out of the `void Update` method so it's a private method within the `class AntagonisticElCreator`.

Comment: now it says variable hasnt been assigned

Comment: variable character hasnot been assigned

Comment: @user245548 It should also tell you which variable at which line.

Comment: You should probably need to assign character value of AntagonisticElcreator

Comment: This is Unassigned Ref Exception no line

Comment: @user245548 You can see the line when you go to the console tab in Unity and double-click on the exception. You should see the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: UnityEngine.Transform.get_position ()
AntagonisticElCreator.Update () (at Assets/AntagonisticElCreator.cs:59)

Comment: transform.LookAt(character.position);

Comment: @user245548 `character` is a public variable, so it is likely supposed to be set in the inspector in the Unity editor by dragging a specific game object into it.

Answer (score 0):

i can see the following

1. Is this the whole script? And if so is it getting any errors? Cause
   i see for example that distance is not declared and the shootAt()
   function  is inside Update().
2. Declare your distance variable.
3. Try to make the initializations in the Start() and not in the Class
   body. ( example. public bool move=false; )
4. In your Update(), i guess
   pos is the position of the character. Please check your Y axis input
   here ( you get x,z from character but y from enemy)

Nik

Comment: it syas keyword void cannot be used in ths cotext

Comment: This is because you have declared a function, inside another function which is wrong.

Write code in a proper code editor in order to identify your errors.

Comment: it says variable character hasnot been assigned

Comment: @user245548 then assign it. Select the script in the Inspector and click the little circle next to the "Character" field to select the transform in your scene that this variable should refer to.